# Show character limit under input in React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a react input component and need to show the character limit underneath the input ex: (0/500 characters remaining). I have passed the maxLength as a prop into the input component but am unsure of how to show the number of characters remaining before the limit is reached.

The max length works properly - how can I add the visual feedback of showing how many characters are remaining (2/500 characters... etc).

```
<input
    {...customAttributes}
    maxLength={maxLength}
    required={required}
/>
```

And then I call my component like so:

```
<InputComponent maxLength={10} />
```

Comment: `<div>Remaining: {this.props.maxLength - this.state.whateverYouNamedTheValue.length}</div>` ?

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not have enough information to answer correctly, but based on the reaction to the comment, something like this should work:

```
<div>
    {this.props.maxLength - this.state.whateverYouNamedTheValue.length}/{this.props.maxLength}
</div>
```

In the context of a component, cleaned up with ES6 a bit:

```
class InputComponent extends React.Component {
    // ... class and state stuff ...
    render() {
        const { maxLength } = this.props;
        const { whateverYouNamedTheValue } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    {...customAttributes}
                    maxLength={maxLength}
                    required={required}
                />
                { whateverYouNamedTheValue ? (
                    <div>
                        ({ maxLength - whateverYouNamedTheValue.length }/{ maxLength })
                    </div>
                ) : null }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered the question perfectly.